# How to run services on another thread?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a navigation application and I need a callback to run on another thread rather than the main one. I've search on the internet and I've discovered that you can do such things using ros subscribers as it is shown in this other reference [[1](https://answers.ros.org/question/214629/multiple-callback-queues/)]. In this node I need to use ros service communication. My question is how can I setup my `ros::AdvertiseServiceOptions::create` in order to link that service server advertisment to another thread by using `ros::AsyncSpinner`?

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338322/how-to-run-services-on-another-thread?/) by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2019-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can create a separate callback_queue and associate it with the AsyncSpinner

There's an example and documentation here: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on 2021-09-27**:
Thank you for the guide!